# Why my program is terminated but main thread is run?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++14, qwidget

I run thread in Qmainwindow using thread library not qthread
I not use thread.join but main thread is run but program is terminated
why program is temianted?

```
void MainWindow::onSendMsg()
{
// std::thread trdSend([this](){
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost(clientIP,clientPort.toUInt());
//socket->close();
QLabel *lblMsg = new QLabel;
QByteArray data;

qDebug()<<"New Message";

if(filePath.isNull() || filePath.isEmpty())
{
    qDebug()<<"Message is Text";

    QString msg=leMsg->text();

    qDebug()<<"Message : "<< msg;

    data =msg.toUtf8();
    data.insert(0,'0');
    qDebug()<<"Add Flag To Message";
    //lblMsg->setText(msg);

    qDebug()<<"Message Is Ready";
    socket->write(data);
    std::thread trdSend((Send()),&data);
    //trdSend.join();
    emit addWidget(true,true,data);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally from [**std::thread::~thread**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread):

> `~thread();` (since C++11)
>
> Destroys the thread object.
>
> If `*this` has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.
>
> **Notes**
>
> A thread object does not have an associated thread (and is safe to destroy) after
>
> - it was default-constructed
> - it was moved from
> - `join()` has been called
> - `detach()` has been called

The instance `std::thread trdSend;` is created as local variable.
After the `emit addWidget(true,true,data);` the scope is left and the `trdSend` is destroyed while none of the four conditions is met.

Comment: why program termianted?    trdsend is not main thread

Answer (score 3):

The `std::thread trdSend` leaves scope so its destructor is called without thread being joined. So it is still joinable. Therefore the program is [required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread) to terminate.

It terminates because what your code does is programming error.  It is made that way because we want either:

1. work thread to send our main program some kind of signal about if it succeeded or failed and so our program knows that the work is done and thread can be joined.
2. our main thread to wait in `join` until work is done.
3. `detach` the thread as we don't really care how it went. But that is odd so we have to be explicit there.

Comment: Can you introduce a reference?

Comment: Added reference link to cppreference.

Comment: my program teminated and program ended????!!!!

Comment: @MDev yes, it is required to terminate your program by standard library specification